# Can not search using both cursorMark and timeAllowed

Tags: solr

I am aware that cursorMark and timeAllowed cannot be used together prior to Solr versions 8.8 according to [SOLR-14413](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-14413) , however the issue I am running into is for an older version of Solr (8.3) and I am not including the timeAllowed parameter in the request, but I still get the 400 error:
Error from server at null: Can not search using both cursorMark and timeAllowed

I am making the following request:

```
http://<host>.com:<port>/solr/<core>/select?q=*%3A*&rows=10&sort=id+asc&cursorMark=*
```

I have not configured any additional details to my /select handler in solrconfig.xml so it should be using whatever default values. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at the output from the response when adding `debug=all`? The sent query parameters should be included in the default response as well, but that should at least give you everything that's available - that should tell you if a `timeAllowed` value is being set by something else.

Comment: I would add `echoParams=all` to properly see in the responseHeader output which parameters are actually passed to the request handler (I'm not sure `debug=true` does that or even can do that because of the bad request error). Also, if there is no `timeAllowed` param set in the /select handler config, yet it could be set _outside_ of the handler config, within a `<initParams>` section.

Comment: @EricLavault You are right, debug=true does not return any additional information because of the bad request error. As for echoParams=all I don't see any timeAllowed parameter. Just the following: q, shards, hostname, echoParams, cursorMark, sort, rows, rid. I rechecked my solrconfig and no I do not have any <initParams> set

Comment: Mmm.. that's strange, the error tells us it's set somewhere but I've no clue where it could be set other than in the requestHandler or initParams config. I would search the entire config dir for the string 'timeAllowed' before getting to a conclusion. Hopefully you can still override it by adding `timeAllowed=-1` to the query.

Comment: @EricLavault Appreciate the help, I was able to find timeAllowed configured in the searchHandler of one of my slave Solr cores Solrconfig. However, interesting to note that adding timeAllowed=-1 actually ended up giving me a successful response, overriding the searchHandler's configuration. Thanks for the help!